# Google Script - Calendar events not owned by me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to write a script to delete event invites from my personal google calendar. I get invited to multiple events everyday such as "Click here to win an iPhone" etc.

I have written a google script to run each hour and delete any events where I am not the owner. However this is getting all events and then iterating through them to see if I am the owner in a for loop. This seems quite inefficient and takes a long time to run.

Is there a better way to achieve this.

Current code below:

```
function deleteScamCalendarInvites() {

  var date = new Date();
  var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear() + 5, date.getMonth(), 1);

  var myCalendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var myEvents = myCalendar.getEvents(firstDay, lastDay);

  for(var i in myEvents){
    if(myEvents[i].isOwnedByMe() == false){
       var eventId = myEvents[i];
       eventId.deleteEvent();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that question would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.    If there is a problem with your code ie it doesnt work we can help you fix errors we cant really tell you the best way to code something

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, I'll post there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end you still need to iterate over the list of events you don't own. So there is nothing much you can do there.

What would be nice is trying to reduce the number of events to lookup, if you know who are the authors that have invited you to these events you could use [`getEvents(startTime, endTime, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date,Object)). You can try to filter by the `options` parameter with the `author`'s that aren't you. Also if they have a pattern you could use the `search` parameter to reduce the number of events.

Comment: I can't find a pattern that links them other than I'm not the owner. The authors are always different, event names are different etc. What I have works fine, it just feels like it's inefficient to get all events. Thanks for your help. I'll stick with what I have